# Using Subclass With Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to implement a 'quit' application with message dialogs. I defined 'Notepad' as a subclass of Qwidget. Then, I defined a 'quit' method.

My code:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QPushButton>

class Notepad : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Notepad();

    private slots:
    void quit();

private:
    QTextEdit *textEdit;
    QPushButton *quitButton;
};

Notepad::Notepad()
{
    textEdit = new QTextEdit;
    quitButton = new QPushButton(tr("Quit"));

    connect(quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(quit()));

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(textEdit);
    layout->addWidget(quitButton);

    setLayout(layout);

    setWindowTitle(tr("Notepad"));
}

void Notepad::quit()
{
    QMessageBox messageBox;
    messageBox.setWindowTitle(tr("Notepad"));
    messageBox.setText(tr("Do you really want to quit?"));
    messageBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
    messageBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::No);
    if (messageBox.exec() == QMessageBox::Yes)
        qApp->quit();
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);


    Notepad k;

    return a.exec();

}
```

The errors:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl Notepad::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@Notepad@@UEBAPEBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __cdecl Notepad::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@Notepad@@UEAAPEAXPEBD@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __cdecl Notepad::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@Notepad@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const Notepad::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@Notepad@@2UQMetaObject@@B)
```

I couldn't understand where the problem is.

Comment: Try to declare `Notepad` class in a header file and its implementation in a .cpp file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just strange behavior of Qt. You shouldn't place any class definitions into main.cpp.
So just separate code:

Notepad.h

```
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QPushButton>

class Notepad : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Notepad();

    private slots:
    void quit();

private:
    QTextEdit *textEdit;
    QPushButton *quitButton;
};
```

Notepad.cpp

```
#include "Notepad.h"
Notepad::Notepad()
{
    textEdit = new QTextEdit;
    quitButton = new QPushButton(tr("Quit"));

    connect(quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(quit()));

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(textEdit);
    layout->addWidget(quitButton);

    setLayout(layout);

    setWindowTitle(tr("Notepad"));
}

void Notepad::quit()
{
    QMessageBox messageBox;
    messageBox.setWindowTitle(tr("Notepad"));
    messageBox.setText(tr("Do you really want to quit?"));
    messageBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
    messageBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::No);
    if (messageBox.exec() == QMessageBox::Yes)
        qApp->quit();
}
```

And main.cpp

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include "Notepad.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Notepad k;
    k.show();    //Also you forgot this line. Without this it just invisible app will be

    return a.exec();

}
```

Comment: I applied your suggestion. However, it gives same errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use QObject's Signal-Slot mechanism you have to declare your class in header file to allow moc to preprocess it.